# Duplicate photo by file content in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to store the file content of a photo (either a png or jpg) into a variable and then use that to create an identical photo. The final script will remote into many machines and use the photo, so copying/pasting the content will be much quicker than transferring the actual file over.

Here is what I have so far, that is not working:

```
C:\Temp> $PhotoContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\photo_orig.jpg" -AsByteStream
C:\Temp> Set-Content -Path "C:\Temp\photo_duplicate.jpg" -Value $PhotoContent
C:\Temp> Set-Content -Path "C:\Temp\photo_duplicate.jpg" -Value $PhotoContent -AsByteStream
Set-Content: Cannot proceed with byte encoding. When using byte encoding the content must be of type byte.
C:\Temp> $PhotoContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\photo_orig.jpg" -Encoding byte
Get-Content: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Encoding'. 'byte' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. (Parameter 'name')
C:\Temp>
```

The first `Set-Content` completed, but the file was 0 KB. I am sure that I am just missing an encoding of some kind, but does anybody know if this is possible?

EDIT: `Copy-Item` will not suffice because I need to copy the photo several remote servers, and need the script to run as quickly as possible. Instead of transferring the file over to each server individually, I was hoping to copy the contents of a photo, pass them as an argument in `Invoke-Command` and then put the contents into a new file on each remote machine

Comment: I must ask: is there a reason you aren't just... well, COPYING the file? with `Copy-Item`?

Comment: Yes. The final script will gather a list of over 1000 machines, remote into each one, and perform an action based on the photo. I am looking for the quickest way for the script to run to get the photo onto each machine. I thought about just copying/transferring the file over, but it would take a vast amount of time to SFTP the file over 1000 times, hence why I am looking into copying the contents, passing that as an argument, and putting that into a new file on the remote machine

Comment: Unless I'm missing something... what you say has no sense whatsoever. The amount of data you'd need to send to copy the file is the exact same amount you'd need to send the content of the file. Because passing the entire content of a file _IS_ copying the file.

Comment: Ok fine then. At the very least I'd like to see if my original question is possible, at the very least just to learn about how encoding works

Comment: using `-AsByteStrem` returns a Object Array(where each object is a byte). Use `-AsByteStream -Raw` to get a Byte Array or `[System.io.file]::ReadAllBytes($PathToTheFile)` instead. This way `Set-Content -AsByteStream` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the comments and testing it out, `Copy-Item` will be the best way to do this. According to this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.4#parameters:%7E:text=Specifies%20that%20the%20content%20should%20be%20written%20as%20a%20stream%20of%20bytes.%20This%20parameter%20was%20introduced%20in%20PowerShell%206.0.) the `-AsByteStream` parameter was added in PowerShell 6.0. Given that most of my machines are running PowerShell 5.x, this will not be feasible. I also ran some speed tests, and `Copy-Item` was indeed faster than copying the photo content. For 100 iterations, `Copy-Item` took 17 seconds, while passing the parameters took 26 seconds. I will still provide a solution for both methods:

**Photo Content**

```
$PhotoContent= Get-Content "[SourceFilepath]" -AsByteStream -Raw
Set-Content -Path "[DestinationFilePath]" -Value $PhotoContent-AsByteStream
```

**Copy-Item**

```
$Credential = [your credentials]
$server = [servername]
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential
Copy-Item "[SourceFilepath]" -Destination "[DestinationFilePathOnServer]" -ToSession $Session
```

For anybody reading this in the future, `Copy-Item` will be the better method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need `Copy-Item`

```
Copy-Item C:\Temp\photo_orig.jpg -Destination C:\Temp\photo_duplicate.jpg
```

[Copy-Item at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: The final script will gather a list of over 1000 machines, remote into each one, and perform an action based on the photo. I am looking for the quickest way for the script to run to get the photo onto each machine. I thought about just copying/transferring the file over, but it would take a vast amount of time to SFTP the file over 1000 times, hence why I am looking into copying the contents, passing that as an argument, and putting that into a new file on the remote machine